# Is there a standard, modern reference on Stoicism?

Tags: reference-request, stoicism

What I'm wondering is if there are any well known, modern references (books) that summarize the history and philosophy of Stoicism, preferably written in the past 50 years or so. The more modern the better. I can negotiate on the history part, but if I can get both in one book that'd be great.

A modern title that gives Stoicism an academic / philosophical treatment, and not just a popular book with a bunch of fluff.

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/stoicism/ good entry and check out the bibliography

Comment: I don't know about "standard", but [Pigliucci's How to Be a Stoic](https://www.amazon.com/How-Be-Stoic-Ancient-Philosophy/dp/1541644530) comes up a lot.

Comment: See [The Cambridge Companion to Stoics](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Cambridge_Companion_to_the_Stoics/34ZsoQBoOU8C) and see Sellars, [Stoicism](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Stoicism/D7jCBQAAQBAJ)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that's perfect, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :-)